# Bond approximations

Tags: fixed-income, bond, bond-yields

I was wondering where a couple of bond math approximations came from (aside from just 'feel'):

1. Pull to par impact:
   I've seen this as (Coupon - YTM) / Yrs to Maturity which is approximately the capital gain/loss on the bond as time evolves and it pulls to par (i.e. YTM -> Coupon).
2. I've seen one which is (YTM - Repo) which is approximately equal to carry. Is this because we are assuming YTM is approx equal to Running Yield of the bond (where Running yield = Coupon Income/Price). Furthermore, this is an annual number so it would probably need some scaling. i.e. (YTM-Repo) x (days to delivery/360).

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you pls cite some sources for these approximations?

Comment: unfortunately - nothing formal, more scouring this forum (other similar ones)/verbal. Probably why there is also a lack of 'proof'